# Find the minimum length snippet from the paragraph that contains all the words belonging to a given query in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm

Given a review paragraph and keywords, find minimum length snippet from paragraph which contains all keywords in any order.If there are millions of review, what preprocessing step would you do.
The first part is simple, just the minimum window problem. Now, for preprocessing, I use inverted index. So, for each review I build a table storing the list of occurance of each word. Now, when a query comes, I retrieve the list of indices for each word. Now, is there some way to find out the min window length from this set of list in O(n) time? I tried building min and max heap to store the current index of each list and then keeping a track of the min window length(using the root of both the heaps). Then I perform extractMin operation and remove the same element from the max heap as well. To keep address of the location of each element in the max heap(for removal), I maintain a hash table. Now from the list, to which the extracted element belonged, I insert the next element into both the heaps and change the window length, if needed. This takes O(nlog n) time. Is it possible to do this in O(n) time?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this combination is sorted here is how I would do it:

- Create a list of objects that describe the word and its index, Something like Obj(String name,Int index).
- Init a set containing all keywords of the query.
- Init the lower bound of the window as the index of the first element in the list.
- Go through the list updating the upper bound of the window as the current object's index, updating the lower bound of the window as the index of the first occurrence of any of the words in your query (i.e. once min_window is set to the index of an actual word occurrence it is no longer updated) and by removing the corresponding word from the set of keywords.
- When the set is empty, save the resulting lower and upper bound along with the length of the snippet.
- Repeat the steps 2 to 5 but this time the list you're going to use is the list that starts at the element that comes right after the one defined by the previous min_window and by only keeping the min_window and max_window if the length of the snippet is shorter than the previous one (this should be repeated until you can no longer find all occurrences in the given sublist).

Comment: Can you please explain your approach with the following example? The review is abc def abc xyz def abc and the query string is def abc abc xyz. So, now the table will be abc- 0,2,5 def-1,4 xyz-3. Hence you will start with lower bound of the window as 0 and you remove it from the set. Now you traverse the set and update the upper bound to 1, remove it and again make the upper bound=3 and remove it. Hence the window size you get=4(3-0+1). But the required window size is 3(5-3+1). Can you pls correct me.

Comment: Where is the example?

Comment: Example: The review is abc def abc xyz def abc and the query string is def abc abc xyz. So, now the table will be abc- 0,2,5 def-1,4 xyz-3. Hence you will start with lower bound of the window as 0 and you remove it from the set. Now you traverse the set and update the upper bound to 1, remove it and again make the upper bound=3 and remove it. Hence the window size you get=4(3-0+1). But the required window size is 3(5-3+1).

Comment: Ok, when reading the review, you are able to generate the following list: L=(abc,0),(def,1),(abc,2),(xyz,3),(def,4),(abc,5). Now this list is sorted by word index.
On the side consider the set S=(abc,def,xyz).
let's set window_min=window_max=0 (index of first element of the list) at first.
Then we go through the list updating the values of S and window_max:
- At element (abc,0), window_max=0 and S=(xyz,def).
- At element (def,1), window_max=1 and S=(xyz).
- At element (xyz,3), window_max=3 and S=().
When S is empty, we stop and thus we have window_min=0 and window_max=3.

Comment: This whole thing is O(m+n) where m is the length of the review and n is the sum of the numbers of occurrence of each word.

Comment: Consider the review to be the same as above. Let the query string be abc xyz. Your method gives  max_window as 3 and min_window as 0, which is wrong. It should give max_window=3 and min_window as 2.

Comment: I just edited my answer to take in consideration the need to return the shortest snippet. The solution is not O(n) and I doubt that you can achieve that if you want to shortest snippet as you have to compare all the different snippet's lengths.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
map<string,int>word;
void functionlower(string& str){
    transform(str.begin(),str.end(),str.begin(),::tolower);
}
string compareWord(string& str){
    string temp;
    temp.resize(str.size());
    transform(str.begin(),str.end(),temp.begin(),::tolower);
return temp;
}
int main(){
int total_word;
cin>>total_word;
for(int i=0;i<total_word;i++){
    string str;
    cin>>str;
    functionlower(str);
    word.insert({str,0});
}

cin.ignore();
string str;
vector<string>para;
getline(cin,str);
int index=0;
for(int i=0;i<=str.size();i++){
    if(i==str.size()||str[i]==' '){para.push_back(str.substr(index,i-index)); index=i+1;}
}
int currlen=0;
int currpos=0;
int lenprint=0;
int olen=-1;
int opos=-1;
for(int i=0;i<para.size();i++){
    string search=compareWord(para[i]);
    if(word.find(search)!=word.end()){
        if(word[search]==0)currlen++;
        word[search]++;
    }
    while(currlen>=word.size()){
        search=compareWord(para[currpos]);
        if((i-currpos)<olen||olen==-1){
            olen=i-currpos;
            opos=currpos;
        }
        if(word.find(search)!=word.end()){
            if(word[search]==1)break;
            word[search]--;
            currpos++;
            lenprint=i;
        }else currpos++;
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<=olen;i++){
cout<<para[opos+i]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

O(nlogk) where k is number of words need to search

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a constant wordLength, this solution can be achieved in O(n) time complexity, where n is number of words in para; here is the code for implementation in java:

```java
package Basic.MinSnippetWithAllKeywords;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * Given a review paragraph and keywords,
 * find minimum length snippet from paragraph which contains all keywords in any order.
 */

public class Solution {
    public String minSnippet(String para, Set<String> keywords) {
        LinkedList<Integer> deque = new LinkedList<>();
        String[] words = para.split("\\s");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
            if(keywords.contains(words[i]))
                deque.offer(i);
        }

        while(deque.size() > 1) {
            int first = deque.pollFirst();
            int second = deque.peekFirst();
            if (words[first] != words[second]) {
                deque.offerFirst(first);
                break;
            }
        }

        while(deque.size() > 1) {
            int first = deque.pollLast();
            int second = deque.peekLast();
            if(words[first] != words[second]) {
                deque.offerLast(first);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (deque.isEmpty())
            return "";

        return String.join(" ",
                Arrays.copyOfRange(words, deque.peekFirst(), deque.peekLast() + 1));
    }
    /*
    Example:
    my name is shubham mishra
    is name
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String para = sc.nextLine();
        String keyLine = sc.nextLine();
        Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<>();
        keywords.addAll(Arrays.asList(keyLine.split("\\s")));
        System.out.println(new Solution().minSnippet(para, keywords));
    }
}
```